# Select and Update using same query in SQL SERVER c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an table `tblHistory' with following columns as shown in picture

[image: tblHistory]

and another table `tblDue`with following columns as shown in picture

[image: tblDue]

What i am trying to do is get the sum of `amountdue` from `tblHistory` with `checked=0` and then update that sum to column `amountdue` on `tblDue`.

All new row added to `tblHistory` will have `checked=0` initially and after retrieving the sum and updating the `tblDue`, it needs to be `checked=1` on `tblHistory` so that checked row will not be added again.

Please help me how this can be done.

What i have tried till now

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                string regdno = txtRegdno.Text;
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select  Sum(isnull(cast(amountdue as float),0)) as amountdue from tblHistory where regdno = '" + txtRegdno.Text + "' and checked='0' , sqlConnection);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {

                    textBox1.Text = (sqlReader["amountdue"].ToString());



                    }


                }

                sqlReader.Close();
            }
```

This returns sum of all 'amountdue' . I want to sum only that having 'checked=0' and then after calculating sum its value must be 'checked=1' AND for new rows again it must sum for 'checked=0'

Comment: Can the new rows that are added to `tblHistory` have the same `regdno` as a previous load? I mean, may the aggregate `amountdue` value need to be updated?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you doing this in C# or are you trying to do this in SQL?

Comment: @Andrew yes they have same regdno and yes aggregate sum must be updated to tblDue and those aggregated rows must have checked=1

Comment: Are `id` columns set as identity?

Comment: i am doing this in c# @Hammerstein.

Comment: @Andrew nope they are not

Comment: So what are those `id` fields for? Do you want to update them in SQL or from C#? If the latter, how are you connecting to the database? EntityFramework, Linq2SQL?

Comment: Why would you do that in C# instead of the database itself? It's MUCH more complex and slow. Also, updating a textbox in a `while`, overwriting the previous value each time?

Comment: @Sdp, still there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in the database, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblDue
SELECT regdno, SUM(amountdue)
FROM tblHistory
WHERE checked = 0
AND regdno NOT IN (SELECT regdno FROM tblDue)
GROUP BY regdno

UPDATE d
SET amountdue = SUM(h.amountdue)
FROM tblDue d
INNER JOIN tblHistory h ON d.regdno = h.regdno
WHERE d.regdno IN (SELECT regdno FROM tblHistory WHERE checked = 0)
GROUP BY d.regdno

UPDATE tblHistory
SET checked = 1
WHERE regdno IN (SELECT regdno FROM tblDue)
```

I didn't create the tables so I didn't test this, there might be issues, but you get the idea of the approach needed.

I assumed those `id` fields were identity, so I ignored them. If they must be taken into consideration for the logic, I can update the query.

Comment: i have updated the question with c# code  i am tried so far.

Comment: after the code i have updated to get checked=1. The problem i am having is next time, it just adds checked=0 value, and discards the previous obtained sum. I want new  sum to be added on the previous sum

Comment: Does my script have that issue? I have considered that. The `INSERT` is for totally new `regdno` and the `UPDATE` is for existing ones, so it sums everything, disregarding the `checked` status.

Comment: @Sdp, I was waiting for your reply. What happened with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you cannot do a `select` and an `update` in the same (one) statement they are two distinct operations.